# Spring boot logger logs nothing

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I created a Spring MVC project using Spring Boot (1.5.8.RELEASE). I picked web, jpa and mysql, and added absolutely nothing in my `build.gradle`.

Here is the relevant part of my `application.yml`:

```
logging:
  level: trace
```

That's all the configuration about logging. I just want the log messages to be shown in the console, so I just omit the `logging.path`.

And I have the controller

```
package com.example.controllers;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
// other imports ...

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DummyController {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyController.class);

  @GetMapping
  public void foo() {
    LOGGER.info("foo");
  }
}
```

When I send a request to `/`, I get a `200 OK` response, but nothing appears in the log. Strangely, the log messages of Spring framework and Hibernate do appear in the console. Just my ad-hoc log messages missing.

Then I debugged my code, and saw that the ancestor of `LOGGER` (the root of the logger tree) is a logger with log level `INFO`. That's apparently not the logger I configured. However, the official documentation of Spring doesn't tell me how to get the logger instance I want. How can I do this? Is there something wrong with my code, or do I miss something in the configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels) is straightforward that the root logger can be configured using `logging.level.root`. But you actually can configure logging for each package/class individually

```
logging.level.root=TRACE                     # default for everything
logging.level.com.example.controllers=TRACE  # for your controllers package
```

Similar application.yml:

```
logging:
 level:
   root: TRACE 
   com.example.controllers: TRACE
```

Comment: Then how to get the logger instance in my Java code? There's not even one line of Java code on that page.

Comment: hm, you code looks fine to me, you approach  `private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyController.class);`  gives you the instance and the recommended way to go. It feels kinda obvious, so probably i'm missing something. And i think in the code you show above any logger should print `logger.info()` message, so you should see `foo` no matter which logging lever you have. And i just checked this in new project

Comment: @Aetherus are you sure you don't have https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration any other logging files in you project? And there is no java code in spring docs because you are actually using Logback + slf4j  https://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html The first line in spring docs states that you can choose one of preconfigured loggers, so there is no point to copy each logger docs. And my answer was just pointing out that you yaml is invalid and that's why you have default INFO root logger parent

Comment: nevermind. I just figured out that `logging.level = trace` is not enough to set all the logging levels of all packages in my project. For example, the JPA entity classes' logging level remains `INFO` with my original configuration. I manually set the levels for each class and it works fine. Just wonder why the loggers in those classes don't respect the global configuration.

Answer (score 0):

IF you take a look to below link
http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/apache/log4j/Level.html

TRACE level is below INFO and you are trying to log info so you are not able to see the log

```
logging.level.com.abc.app=DEBUG
```

where com.abc.app is your root dir of your application